# merge attachments from two emails into one?

Tags: email, postfix

Is it possible to merge two emails sent to the same address within a couple of minutes into just one email? I'm dealing with some software that sends invoices in one email and a statement in another and I'd really just like them to be in one email. Can I do this with postfix? Or is there some other way of doing it? Like emailing it to a 'local' email address and then they get repackaged locally? Not sure if I should be asking here or on Superuser or Stackoverflow! :-)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But don't do that in a business environment. Have it fixed where it is caused, rewriting mail later has all sorts of annoying edge cases (what do you do if you get a duplicate? Or one statement with 2 accompanying invoices?)

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic due to unsupported Software - however, fix that Point with the Vendor of your Software, not after the child was already into the water well

Comment: @anx would you consider letting me know what I'd begin Googling for? The business software developers aren't interested in fixing this issue. I'm prepared for occasional annoying edge cases. Thanks